# Angular 4 load event with @HostListener

Tags: javascript, angular

This is what I am trying to do:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[appResizeWindow]'
})
export class ResizeWindowDirective {
@Input('appResizeWindow') line_ChartOptions: {};

constructor() { }

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) onResize(event: Event) {
console.log('Yo');
if (event.target['innerWidth'] < 420)
  this.line_ChartOptions['hAxis']['format'] = 'MMM';
else if (event.target['innerWidth'] < 760)
  this.line_ChartOptions['hAxis']['format'] = 'MM. yy\'';
else this.line_ChartOptions['hAxis']['format'] = 'MMM d, yyyy';
}

@HostListener('load', ['$event']) onPageLoad(event: Event) {
   console.log('loaded');
   this.onResize(event.target['innerWidth']);
  }
}
```

So 'window.resize' works perfect when I attack in in the template.

The problem is with **load**. I event tried **onload**

I want the page to execute when the page is loaded.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `load` event has already happened before your component/directive is even initialized.

Just add your code to `ngAfterViewInit()`
If your component/directive is removed and re-added after it was first initialized, you need to take care yourself that the code isn't executed more than once by using a global service or a static variable to store the status.

Comment: To the Directive itself?

Comment: @onetwo12 I know what lifecycle hooks are. What I do not understand is How do I make a connection between the content inside AfterViewInit (which is inside the Component) and the HostListener on the Directive?

Comment: @JonathanTugg you can use the directive if it is added when the application is initially loaded (when it's in the AppComponent) or to any component or directive that is added to AppComponent or one of it's children (without an `*ngIf` or similar that could prevent it to be added on application load)

Comment: Oh I should put my code which is currently inside my ngOnInit inside the AfterViewInit. Am I right?

Comment: A general example could be cool. Anyway I have marked this topic as solved since it did give me a hint about my problem.

Comment: @JonathanTugg how did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 4):

try this one, this will work.

```
@HostListener('window:load',['$event'])
onPageLoad(event: Event) {
   console.log('loaded',event); 
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how it solves the issue?

Answer (score -2):

i solved this using OnInit

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

inside your component class put this..

```
ngOnInit() {
  // Code to be executed on Init
}
```