# @HostListener not working in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the @HostListener to work on page load. I have a responsive table that isn't very responsive on page load because host listener isn't registering the width of the page until I adjust it manually. Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131295/4350389), I should add the host listener to ngAfterViewInit(). Make sense, but when I add it there it says it expects an argument.

[image]

but I don't have this problem when I place it above the constructor instead. It works. Just not on page load this way

[image]

How can I get host listener to play nicely and work on page load?

mobile.detect.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT4 = 764;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScreenSizeService {
  private mediaMatcher5: MediaQueryList =
    matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT4}px)`);
  constructor(
  ) { }
  dashboardCheck(): boolean {
    return this.mediaMatcher5.matches;
  }

}
```

Comment: can your restart your IDE,Edit:  Indeed it is giving warning i don't know it can be use inside ngAfterViewInit and hostlistener is global event.

Comment: I closed and reopened vscode and issue still persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should NEVER put Hostlistener inside any other methods**

The answer you're referening implies that you don't need to move `@Hostlistener` to `ngAfterViewInit` but rather execute relavant code there.

```
@HostListener('window:resize)
onResize() {
  // your code goes here
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.onResize();
}
```

Comment: This is what I did in the second screenshot above, but HostListener doesn't activate until I adjust the width of the browser. I need it to activate on page load

Comment: Did you notice that I activate it inside ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: I overlooked that. I tried it and it's working! Thanks so much! I'll release the bounty when it lets me in 24 hours